# Custom message for wrong format in validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my models/user.rb I have this validates

```
  validates :username, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                       length: { in: 3..15 },
                       format: { with: /\A[^\.]+\z/ },
                       format: { without: /\s/ }
```

three questions:

1. can I write the regex differently? Just in a one line.
2. if the user try to sign up as "Magic Mike", it says "it is invalid". But it is too generic. How to edit it to write "no white/blank spaces" ?
3. can I disallow the space bar during the signup? How to do in rails? Should I use javascript?

Comment: Can you give us cases of what you would like to have and not like to have in usernames.?

Comment: i want to have usernames with all kinds of characters (also japanese, chinese, corean, etc.) and without symbols like . % , |, etc. And without white/blank space

Comment: If you want to have separate messages for each validation, you should have the length as a separate validation, format as a separate validation. Not sure about the other languages though

Answer (score 0):

You just want 'no spaces' and 'only letters' right?

```rb
/^\w+$/
```

you can also include the length requirement in the regex:

```rb
/^\w{3,15}$/
```

You can't actually disallow the space bar. But in javascript you can show an error if the space character is inserted in the field, and you can remove the space from the input field.

If you wish to show a more explanatory message, use the message: option:

```rb
validates :username, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false, message: 'must be unique'}
validates :username, format: {with: /^\w{3,15}$/, message: 'must be 3-15 letters with no spaces'}
```

Comment: Does it work also with chinese/japanese/korean characters? and numbers? How to edit the "error message"? Now it says only "is not valid". It's not so clear...

Comment: This solution works. it will give only a single message. If you want a separate validation message for length, you will have to add the separate length validation as you have in your question

Comment: I don't know if this will work with chinese etc. characters, I've added custom messages to my answer fyi

Answer (score 0):

The standard regex matchers (`\w, \s`, etc.) only work with standard ASCII characters. However, ruby 1.9+ supports POSIX bracket expressions, such as `[[:alpha:]]` to match Unicode characters (Chinese, Korean, etc.). So, the equivalent to @Les's nicely compact regex for Unicode would be:

```rb
/^[[:alpha:]]{3,15}$/
```

For example:

```rb
s = '큰사과'
s.match(/[[:alpha:]]{3,15}/)
=> #<MatchData "큰사과">
```

With whitespace:

```rb
s = '큰 사과'
s.match(/[[:alpha:]]{3,15}/)
=> nil
```

The Ruby docs for [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#top) list all the supported bracket expressions.

You can use the `:message` option to set a custom validation message:

```rb
validates :username, format: {with: /^\[[:alpha:]]{3,15}$/, message: 'no whitespace allowed'}
```

Comment: what do you think if I add just format: { without: /[\s\.\%\&]/ } ?

Comment: You know your use case best, but generally you want the simplest regex that covers your case. If that ``:without`` does what you need, go for it. You'll need to specify ``:length`` validation separately, but If you want to set custom messages for each that's probably what you want anyway.